# GCP Kubernetes cannot connect to RabbitMQ server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq

I have a docker image on the google cloud platform that I would like to run. Part of this script attempts to connect to a RabbitMQ server (located in the same subnet). This does not work.

I've taken the following steps to try and solve it:

- I have tried connecting to both the internal and external IP-address of the RabbitMQ server.
- I have enabled VPC-native (alias IP)
- I have checked I can connect to the internet from my docker image
- I have checked that my docker image can connect to RabbitMQ when run locally
- I have checked that the server can connect to the internal IP-address from the RabbitMQ server (by pinging it)

I think I probably have an incorrect setting in my kubernetes engine, but I've looked for quite some time and I cannot find it.

Does anybody know how to connect to a RabbitMQ server from a Kubernetes pod running in the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: I've found a 'hack' by connecting to the external IP-address, this originally did not work because of a firewall setting. I would still like to know how to connect to the internal IP-address

Comment: Is RabbitMQ running inside GKE Kubernetes?

Comment: @Patt-tomMcDonnell RabbitMQ is running on a seperate VM instance on the same subnet

Comment: It sure would help to see some error output.

Comment: @LukeBakken I agree, unfortunately all it says is `Failed to connect to RabbitMQ broker <myipaddres>: Connection to <myipaddress>:<myportnumber> failed: timeout`

Comment: Have you checked your firewall rules for RabbitMQ server ?

Comment: @manasouza I have, I was able to whitelist my IP so that I could access it via the external IP-address, but I suppose there's a similar setting for internal IP addresses

Comment: @Nathan you meant even if with the `default-allow-internal` fw rule it does not work.
Example of this fw rule:
Ingress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 10.128.0.0/9 | tcp:0-65535 udp:0-65535 icmp | Allow | 65534 | default

Comment: @manasouza exactly, somebody else on the team has figured it out in the meantime though.